# How to change the theme using theme preference of the user and how to safe the preference selected when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript

I'm a new person in programing, I'm trying to change the theme of my website portfolio using my pc's theme. But when I change the theme of my pc the website theme stay the same.

I want to change the website theme by using the theme of the pc, and when the user change the theme usign the button this stay on the another pages

var ctheme = document.getElementById("ctheme");
const $html = document.querySelector('html');

```
// Verificar a preferência do usuário no carregamento da página
if (localStorage.getItem('darkMode') === 'enabled') {
  $html.classList.add('dark-mode');
  ctheme.textContent = "light_mode";
} else {
  // Verificar se o sistema operacional está no modo escuro
  const prefersDarkMode = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;
  if (prefersDarkMode) {
    $html.classList.add('dark-mode');
    ctheme.textContent = "light_mode";
  }
}

ctheme.onclick = function () {
  // Alternar o modo escuro
  $html.classList.toggle('dark-mode');

  // Atualizar a preferência no localStorage
  if ($html.classList.contains('dark-mode')) {
    localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'enabled');
    ctheme.textContent = "light_mode";
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'disabled');
    ctheme.textContent = "dark_mode";
  }
};
```

window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
const newPrefersDarkMode = e.matches;

```
if (newPrefersDarkMode) {
    htmlElement.classList.add('dark-mode');
} else {
    htmlElement.classList.remove('dark-mode');
}
```

});

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code.